# CakePHP uninstall

Tags: cakephp, uninstallation

Might anyone be able to tell me how to uninstall CakePHP 3.0 from a Windows 7 machine? I have searched their docs and the Web--CakePHP's forum is on FreeNode which seems like it would take all day to figure out how to use. I installed it in the wrong place (not under XAMPP, but parallel), could not find how to uninstall it so re-installed it in the right place (htdocs), but the new installation is corrupted with missing files. I would like to take it all out and start over.

Comment: There is no official uninstallation procedure. Assuming you didn't use Composer to install it (doing this will prevent files from getting in the wrong path anyway), simply delete the directory where you downloaded the core framework files to.

Comment: Remove the files from disk => uninstall completed...

Comment: Thank you very much, just erasing the files worked and CakePHP now works. With the installation being a completely black box, I didn't want to try that. In fact I did use Composer to install, which was happy to let me mess up the installation location the first time.